# Check duplicate then copy cell next to duplicate

Tags: excel, vba, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large dataset with duplicates in multiple columns the only exception is that for every duplicate the cell (email) is different. I want to copy that email and place in the same row as the first duplicate.

| ID | SEX | First Name | Last Name | Mail | Phones | Street | Number | Code | City | Contract | Last access | first access |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | John | Doe | jd@mail.com |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | M | John | Doe | Johndoe@gmail.com |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Should be like this

| ID | SEX | First Name | Last Name | Mail | Phones | Street | Number | Code | City | Contract | Last access | first access | SECOND EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | John | Doe | jd@mail.com |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | johndoe@gmail.com |
| deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row | deleted row |

I'm currently doing this in Excel but if this is possible to do in other software, then that's fine by me.
The origin document is a CSV to work with.

Comment: Please show say 10 rows of _realistic-looking_ sample data. Instead of `name1, surname1, email`, show `John Bart, Fidget-Mongrel III, John B. Fidget-Mongrel <johnny.boy@example-site.org>`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easiest if you can share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking but dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA version of how to do this:

```
Sub CondenseDuplicates()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, lastRow As Integer, i as integer
    Dim Name as string, NameList As Object
    
    Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    
    lastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set NameList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
        Name = Sht.Cells(i, 1) & " " & Sht.Cells(i, 2)
        
        If NameList.exists(Name) Then
            'Duplicate Found
            Sht.Cells(NameList(Name), 4) = Sht.Cells(i, 3)
            'save second email and delete the duplicate row.
            Sht.Rows(i).ClearContents
        Else
            'Add Name to List
            NameList.Add Name, i
            'Save the row # for the entry, so it can be referenced later.
        End If
        
    Next i
End Sub
```

This only works for two emails, if you want it to work for more than two emails we just need to change that line `Sht.Cells(NameList(Name), 4) = Sht.Cells(i, 3)`. The `4` references the fourth column, but if that column already contains an email we would want to put it in the next empty cell, which we can reference with `.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1)`

So the full, complicated version of that line is: `Sht.Cells(NameList(Name), 2).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1) = Sht.Cells(i, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

With headers in row 1 and data in `A2:M`, try this spreadsheet formula in Google Sheets:

`=sort( sortn(A2:M, 9^9, 2, C2:C & D2:D, true) )`

Place the formula in the top-left corner of a free range such as `N1:Z`, or put it in another tab in cell `A2` and add `Sheet1!` to every range reference in the formula.

The formula will work with any number of duplicates. Note that it will only keep the rows that mark the first occurrence of each first name – last name pair. With the sample data you quote, it gives the expected result you quote.

Comment: No clue what you mean with your code example?

Comment: It is a spreadsheet formula. In Google Sheets, this sort of thing can be done without resorting to scripting.

Comment: It is an array formula that gets the full result table in one go. You do not need to copy it down. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I have solutioned your problem using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). Assuming that your data starts in `A1`, you can run the following function to obtain the contacts without duplicates. The data starts in `E1`. It works with multiple emails.

### Code

```
function mergeContacts() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var contacts = sheet.getRange("A1:C"+lastRow).getValues()
  var newContacts = [contacts[1]]
  for (var i=2; i<contacts.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<newContacts.length; j++){
      if (contacts[i][0]==newContacts[j][0] && contacts[i][1]==newContacts[j][1]){
        if (contacts[i][2]!=newContacts[j][2]){
          newContacts[j].push(contacts[i][2])
        }        
        break
      }
      newContacts.push(contacts[i])
      break
    }
  }
  newContacts.splice(0,0,contacts[0])
  var m = Math.max.apply(Math, newContacts.map(function (el) { return el.length }));
  for (var i=0; i<newContacts.length; i++){
    var diff = m-newContacts[i].length
    if (diff>0){
      newContacts[i] = newContacts[i].concat(new Array(diff))
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,5,newContacts.length,m).setValues(newContacts)
}
```

Comment: When I run the code It gives me equal amount of original contacts vs "merged" contacts. Which states that there is something not quite working, or I'm doing something wrong. Because I can see there is a difference and that there are indeed duplicates in them. 
I also adjusted the question table to look more real! For better comprehension.